# How to set creation time of existing file in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When copying a file by `FileCopy` (or also `RenameFile`) from a directory to another one an original creation time changes to the current date. I would like to set the creation time to the original one.

I can get the original time values by `FindFirst`, but how to get a handle of a file to use when calling `SetFileTime`?

In the `[Code]` section of Inno Setup, I have this code:

```pascal
If FileCopy(F1, F2,False) then
  If FindFirst(F1,FindRec) then
    Try
      Fhandle := ??????????? (FindRec.FindHandle don't works)
      SetFileTime(
        Fhandle, FindRec.CreationTime, FindRec.LastAccessTime, FindRec.LastWriteTime)
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end
```

---

EDIT:

After the answer of Martin I have modified the code as follow (**sorry if is far than perfect...** I am a VB.NET programmer, not a Pascal programmer):

```pascal
{ C1 and C2 are full Paths }
if Not FileCopy(C1, C2, False) then
   begin
     MsgBox('Data reading error 01. Setup will be aborted.', mbError, MB_OK);
     Result := false;
     exit;
   end;

if FindFirst(C2, FindRec) then 
    try
     begin
      MyTime := FindRec.LastWriteTime //remains the original one
     end;
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end
 else
   begin
     MsgBox('Data reading error 02. Setup will be aborted.', mbError, MB_OK);
     Result := false;
     exit;
    end;
 end;  

 FileStream := TFileStream.Create(C2, fmOpenReadWrite);
 Try
    if not SetFileTime(FileStream.Handle, MyTime, MyTime, MyTime) Then
       begin
        MsgBox('Data reading error 03. Setup will be aborted.', mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := false;
        exit;
     end;
 Finally
    FileStream.Free;
 end;
```

Comment: Why are you manually copying files instead of having IS do it for you? It can do so directly, including setting the file stamp in the process using the flag `Touch`. If you're copying from the same partition, you don't even have to do that; just use the `external` flag.

Comment: I agree! Please accept out answers by ticking them. Not just up voting. We put work into our answers free of charge. By ticking you are building our reputation. Please look at your questions section of your profile and mark those that you can with a tick. Thank you.

Comment: @Martin/Andrew: ops, sorry, I will accept (clicking up harrow, I think)

Comment: @Ken: because the files are EXISTING, them are NOT files stored in the [File] section. Old files created in previous Setups that I have to move in other directory maintaining the creatiin time.

Comment: Then you use the external flag, as I said previously. It copies files from  an **external** location (AKA, not in the setup file).

Comment: I see you now using the newsgroups to ask your questions. Why not accept the answers?

Comment: @Martin @ Andrew: 
Mates... I'm italian and english for me is about arab. Three years at school 40 years ago.  I did'nt know that was a good pratice to accept the answers and then I thinked that to accept answers I had to click the up arrow. Please consider that english language is not the universal one of the planet and not all people read english like a Oxford student.

Comment: You should accept the best answer. And upvote any number of answers (including the accepted answer) that you found useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a handle of a file, you can use [`TFileStream` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TFileStream):

```pascal
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  { ... }
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
  try
    SetFileTime(FileStream.Handle, CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime);
  finally
    FileStream .Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

Though as @Ken wrote, in most cases, it would be easier to use `[Files]` section entry with an [`external` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=external).